# How to submit custom input file type data in php?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I am not able to send the file data to the form's `action` page. I am using Laravel 8.

```
<label for='inputProductDescription' class='form-label'>Product Images</label>
<input id="fancy-file-upload" type="file" name="files[]" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>
```

Using `jquery.fancy-fileupload.js`, this jquery
my action file code:

```
function add_product(Request $req) {
    $images = $req->file('file');
    if($req->hasFile('file')):
        foreach ($images as $item):
            $var = date_create();
            $time = date_format($var, 'YmdHis');
            $imageName = $time . '-' . $item->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $item->move(base_path() . '\public\assets\upload\images', $imageName);
            $arr[] = $imageName;
        endforeach;
    endif;

    return $imageName;
}
```

When I am uploading the image, `$imageName` is giving me an error, it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

declare the $imageName property like global into the method.

```
  $imageName = null;
  $images = $req->hasFile('file') ? $req->file('file') : null;
   if($images)
      foreach ($images as $item)
        $time = now()->format('YmdHis');
        $imageName = $time . '-' . $item->getClientOriginalName();
        $path=  $item->move(base_path() . '\public\assets\upload\images', $imageName);
        $arr[] = $imageName; // seems this is unnecessary line of code
      endforeach;
    endif;


   return $imageName;
```

Comment: Now i did this error is not showing. I am uploading the image but not geting the this variable value ($imageName).  when i am not using id(id="fancy-file-upload") in input filed then code is working fine.                  <input id="fancy-file-upload" type="file" name="files[]" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>